# Is Wallet softwares safe? then how verify?

Tags: transactions, wallet, fraud

Some day, I thought that there are may fraud wallet to steal bitcoin.

It is really very achieved as following:

> User should make a keypair at first time. at this time, wallet
>   software can send keypair to operator's server, but user doesn't know
>   absolutely about this situation unless they capture network packets using Wireshark between wallet and destination address which is forwarded by wallet.

Of course, well-known wallet software may be verified, but I think that we should be careful brandnew wallet software because they are not verified.

Okay, it was my thought so far and my question is:

1. **Is there any software or organization that can verify whether wallet is secure or not?**
2. **If first question's answer is yes, what is the method?**

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Is there any software or organization that can verify whether wallet is secure or not?**

- You can use an open source wallet and take the time to read and understand all the code and then compile it yourself. This would be an unfeasably large task for most ordinary people. Software developers might find it a bit easier but it is still a large amount of work.
- You can use a network sniffer to discover where a standalone wallet on a device you own is sending data.
- You could pay a well-known independent security consultant to perform the above analysis or more likely, arrange for an employee or associate to do this. Someone of the stature of Schneier for example. This would be very expensive.

---

You can avoid the need for this by storing your private keys, and generating transactions, on a computer that is not connected to any network. Then *carefully* move the raw transaction data to a connected machine for transmission. For example use a new clean USB stick for each transaction. The connected machine has no access to your private keys and therefore cannot surreptitiously divulge them. Some software wallets support this (Armory?) and some hardware wallets are used in this manner (Trezor, Ledger).